# TCP/IP communication in Matlab

Tags: matlab, tcp, cluster-analysis

I want to build my own Matlab cluster from lots of junk computers.
Anybody knows how to send data from one Matlab to another over TCP ?
I need to send image chunks / .mat files and variables.

Thanks,
SW

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the Distributed Computing Toolbox ($$$) or the [jPar](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24924-jpar-parallelizing-matlab-calculations-on-multicores-and-in-clusters-without-file-communication) utility from the File Exchange (free)

Answer (score 3):

[TCP/UDP/IP Toolbox 2.0.6](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/345) from Matlab Exchange offers a tcp/ip implementation. When I last checked, about a year ago, it was far more performant than the one available by the "Instrument Control Toolbox" from The MathWorks.