# Can Matlab Pass Data In String To Visual Studio 2010 in real time?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, matlab, matlab-deployment

I am doing some Matlab coding which able pass data to visual Basic 2010 in real time. Anyone of u has any idea about it? And i quite rush for it. Thank You :D

p/s:i apologize for my bad English Gramme,

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used Visual Basic, but at least four different options come into my mind:

1. Save the data to a file in MATLAB, and in Visual Basic poll for file eg. every second, every ten seconds, every minute etc. according to your needs (response time vs. CPU usage).
2. Start Visual Basic from MATLAB and pass the data to Visual Basic as command line arguments. Use Parallel Computing toolbox to keep MATLAB running while Visual Basic is processing earlier set[s] of the data. From MATLAB you can launch new Visual Basic instances/processes and keep older ones alive, or kill them if you wish.
3. In MATLAB, send data as IP packets to some port of 127.0.0.1, and in Visual Basic, keep reading the same port of 127.0.0.1 .
4. In MATLAB, send data as e-mail to a local e-mail address, and in Visual Basic, keep reading the e-mails of the same address.

I think the best solution depends on what are the data, and what you are attempting to do.

Comment: 5. Matlab Builder NE, if you are using VB .NET

Comment: Thank you for ur answer i appreciate so much.But didn't u have any idea how to send data as IP packets?

Comment: MATLAB has [Instrument Control Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.se/products/instrument/index.html) for TCP/IP & UDP communications. In [File Exchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/) there's [TCP/IP Communications in Matlab](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24524), [TCP/UDP/IP Toolbox 2.0.6](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/345) and [MATLAB TCP/IP - code example](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/11802). This question might have useful info: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3591031/tcp-ip-communication-in-matlab].

Answer (score 0):

Make a .Net DLL in VS.  Then load the assembly in Matlab and use it from within Matlab.  Matlab can assign variables directly (i.e. pass to VB) in your class or GUI.